# OleDbException: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '''WIP'''." when updating specific cells

Tags: c#, sql, excel, oledb

I ran into this error when I was trying to update a specific cell on an excel sheet using OleDb. Below is the function that throws the exception.

```
private void WriteExcelFile()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString(excelPath);

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = null;

        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        for (int i = 0; i < valsEdited.Count; i++)
        {
            sql = "update [Sheet1$" + GetColName(colsEdited[i]) + (rowsEdited[i] + 2).ToString() + ":" + GetColName(colsEdited[i]) + (rowsEdited[i] + 2).ToString() + "] set Status='" + valsEdited[i] + "'";
            sql.Replace("'", "''");
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Exception thrown here
        }
        cmd = null;
        conn.Close();

        colsEdited.Clear();
        rowsEdited.Clear();
        valsEdited.Clear();
    }
}
```

I checked a number of times with break points and the sql statements seems fine to me:

```
update [Sheet1$A1:A1] set Status = "Completed"
```

This is driving me crazy here. Please help!

**EDIT:**

Given below are some notes to clarify my code:

`private string GetConnectionString(string s)` returns a connection string to the excel file in question given its path.

`private string GetColName(int i)` returns a string representing the Excel column given its column index in C#.

`List<int> colsEdited` is a list containing all the columns in some DataGridView being edited by the user.

`List<int> rowsEdited` is a list containing all the rows in some DataGridView being edited by the user.

`List<int> valsEdited` is a list containing all the new values edited by the user in some DataGridView.

**UPDATE:**
I have updated the code to reflect the current version of the code. Thanks Lars for catching that error.

Comment: `sql = sql.Replace("'", "''");`

Comment: Oh god. Thanks for catching that. The exception now becomes Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '''WIP'''.